# Slack API - Attachments not showing

Tags: php, slack-api

I've created a (fairly simple) implementation for *Slack* to post certain messages in a channel with *PHP*. All works well, except for the Attachments. For some reason, they do show up for "some" of the messages, but not everything.

The code snippet I'm using is almost identical to this one [here](https://codepad.co/snippet/EN5n1qKP)

```
<?php
/**
 * Slack Incoming Webhook - Single PHP File
 *
 * @author      Chris - http://codepad.co/cheers | https://github.com/webremote
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2016
 * @version     0.0.28
 * @build       20160204
 */
// Settings
$token      = 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx'; // Request your token via https://api.slack.com/tokens
$channel    = '#mandrill-log';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (!empty($_POST['mandrill_events'])) {
        foreach (json_decode($_POST['mandrill_events'], true) as $entry) {
            // Default values
            $attachments = [];
            $type = 'Unknown';
            $emoji = 'question';
            $text = print_r($entry, true);
            switch ($entry['event']) {
                case 'send':
                    $text = 'Sent a mail to ' . $entry['msg']['email'] . ' with subject "' . $entry['msg']['subject'] . '" (from: ' . $entry['msg']['sender'] . ')';
                    $emoji = 'email';
                    $type = 'Sent';
                    break;

                case 'click':
                    $text = 'Somebody from ' . $entry['location']['country'] . ' clicked the URL "' . $entry['url'] . '"';
                    $emoji = 'point_right';
                    $type = 'Click';
                    $attachments = [
                        'fallback'  => $text,
                        'text'      => 'URL clicked: ' . $entry['url'],
                        'fields'    => [
                            [
                                'title' => 'Location',
                                'value' => $entry['location']['country'] . (!empty($entry['location']['region']) ? PHP_EOL . $entry['location']['region'] : '') . (!empty($entry['location']['city']) ? PHP_EOL . $entry['location']['city'] : ''),
                                'short' => true,
                            ],
                            [
                                'title' => 'Browser',
                                'value' => $entry['user_agent_parsed']['type'],
                                'short' => true
                            ],
                            [
                                'title' => 'Subject',
                                'value' => $entry['msg']['subject'],
                                'short' => true,
                            ],
                            [
                                'title' => 'Sender',
                                'value' => $entry['msg']['sender'],
                                'short' => true
                            ]
                        ],
                        'thumb_url' => $entry['user_agent_parsed']['ua_icon']
                    ];
                    break;

                case 'open':
                    $text = 'Somebody from ' . $entry['location']['country'] . ' opened an email "' . $entry['msg']['subject'] . '"';
                    $emoji = 'open_book';
                    $type = 'Read';
                    $attachments = [[
                        'fallback'  => $text,
                        'fields'    => [
                            [
                                'title' => 'Location',
                                'value' => $entry['location']['country'] . (!empty($entry['location']['region']) ? PHP_EOL . $entry['location']['region'] : '') . (!empty($entry['location']['city']) ? PHP_EOL . $entry['location']['city'] : ''),
                                'short' => true,
                            ],
                            [
                                'title' => 'Browser',
                                'value' => $entry['user_agent_parsed']['type'] . ($entry['user_agent_parsed']['mobile'] ? ' - Mobile' : ' - Desktop'),
                                'short' => true
                            ],
                            [
                                'title' => 'Subject',
                                'value' => $entry['msg']['subject'],
                                'short' => true,
                            ],
                            [
                                'title' => 'Sender',
                                'value' => $entry['msg']['sender'],
                                'short' => true
                            ]
                        ],
                        'thumb_url' => $entry['user_agent_parsed']['ua_icon']
                    ]];
                    break;

                case 'soft_bounce':
                    $text = 'Email to ' . $entry['msg']['email'] . ' with subject "' . $entry['msg']['subject'] . '" got (soft) bounced';
                    $emoji = 'space_invader';
                    $type = 'Bounce';
                    break;

                case 'hard_bounce':
                    $text = 'Email to ' . $entry['msg']['email'] . ' with subject "' . $entry['msg']['subject'] . '" got (hard) bounced (' . $entry['msg']['diag'] .')';
                    $emoji = 'skull_and_crossbones';
                    $type = 'Bounce';
                    break;
            }

            if ($entry['type'] == 'blacklist') {
                if ($entry['action'] == 'add') {
                    $type = 'Blacklist';
                    $emoji = 'new_moon_with_face';
                    $text = 'The e-mail ' . $entry['reject']['email'] . ' has been added to the blacklist (Reason: ' . $entry['reject']['reason'] . ', expires at ' . $entry['reject']['expires_at'] . ')';
                }
            }
            
            if (empty($attachments)) {
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,         'Webremote.Mandrill.Webhook');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,              true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,               'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
                    'token'         => $token,
                    'channel'       => $channel,
                    'username'      => 'Mandrill-' . $type,
                    'text'          => $text,
                    'icon_emoji'    => ':' . $emoji . ':'
                ]);
                curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
            } 
            elseif (!empty($attachments)) {
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,         'Webremote.Mandrill.Webhook');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,              false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,               'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?' . http_build_query([
                    'token'         => $token,
                    'channel'       => $channel,
                    'username'      => 'Mandrill-' . $type,
                    'text'          => $text,
                    'attachments'   => json_encode($attachments),
                    'icon_emoji'    => ':' . $emoji . ':'
                ]));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,    1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,        [
                    'content-length: ' . strlen($dataSend)
                ]);
                $response = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For `"case: send" (line 23)` I also want to display attachments, but for some reason, it doesn't work. The result in *Slack* is just the `"text"-field`, whereas attachments get completely ignored for... no good reason?

I've tried searching the API documentation, FAQ and even SO, but no topics showed up. Are there specific reasons why an attachment doesn't show?

Comment: The code above doesn't have any attachments for the 'send' case. Can you share the actual code you're trying?